# Shortcut to Rotate 60 degree via Script

Tags: scripting

I have an object that's a hexagon tile and for quick editing I am trying to make a shortcut key to rotate the object 60 degrees along the z axis, direction doesn't matter.

Could someone show me a python script?  Greatly Appreciated

Like below, only +60 degrees, not set to 60 degrees

import math
bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler[0] = math.radians(60)

Comment: `bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler[0] += math.radians(60)` ?

Comment: maybe you should tell us why you need to rotate so often something to 60 degrees. Sounds like there should be other ways than creating a shortcut for that because i think it's an overkill....

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts, of course, are set up in the keymap in *Preferences*. Creating a short cut requires an [*operator*](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html): typing the shortcut key invokes the operator.  In this instance, there isn't a specific operator so you have to create your own.

Here's one example operator.

```py
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from math import radians

class TLA_OT_rotate60(Operator):
    bl_idname='rotate.rotate60'
    bl_label='rotate 60 degrees'

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None and context.object.mode == 'OBJECT'

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=radians(60))
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
bpy.utils.register_class(TLA_OT_rotate60)
```

Paste this script into the blender text editor and run it to register your new class.  Then you can edit preferences and add a new keymap entry assigning the key of your choice to `rotate.rotate60`.

Aside: If you didn't know how to code the command you wanted to execute, you could go to the *Scripting* workspace and execute that command by hand.  (In this case, the shortcut (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) and look at the output shown in the Info window (`bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.0472, orient_axis='Z', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, False, True), mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)`)  Next look up the command (`bpy.ops.transform.rotate`) in the manual and figure out the exact argument you want.